# Listings without a border?

Tags: listings

I'm using listings to format blocks of code in my LaTeX, and I like it. But, except for large blocks of code, the border around the code block is bulky and breaks up the flow of how I read the document. I've tried searching around for a way to disable this code, but thus far I haven't found anything. Is it just impossible? Seems strange if this is the case.

Comment: Does `\begin{lstlisting}[frame=none]` work?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 15):

Use the  available options for the selected `lstlisting` environments; a litle example in which the style selected uses numbers to the left and a frame on the four sides of the listing; using `frame=<valid values>` and `numbers=<valid values>` one can change the behaviour for selected environments (for a list of all the keys and their `<valid values>` refer to the package documentation):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  frame=lrtb,
  numbers=left
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
test
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=none]
test
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=bt,numbers=none]
test
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Then as a follow-up question, is it possible to selectively enable borders, or otherwise specify options specific to a particular block? For example, if I normally didn't want to display line numbers, but I want to use them on some.

Comment: @limp_chimp of course, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just do `frame=none` after the `language=Java` like this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java, numbers=none, frame=none]
```